# Errors in C++ Code Regarding Functions

Tags: c++

Could somebody kindly explain why am I getting the errors for the following code(I have attached both the code and the errors,just scroll down). Actually this a homework question. I have successfully completed the question in Python previously so now that I was required to do the same question in c++, I basically just copy pasted and changed the syntax but it doesn't somehow work.

## CODE

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float reduce(int num,float denom)
{
    float a;
    if (num>denom)
    {
        a = denom;
    }
    if (denom>num)
    {
        a = num;
    }
    float sol = 0;
    while (a>1)
    {
        if ( (num<=0) || (denom<=0) )
            a = -10;
        if ( (num%a == 0) && (denom%a == 0) )
        {
            sol = 1;
            a = -10;
        }
        a-=1;
    }
    return sol;
}

int main()
{
    float num;float denum;
    cout<<"Numerator: ";cin>>num;
    cout<<"Denominator: ";cin>>denum;
    float sol = Reduce(num,denom);
    cout<<sol;

}
```

## ERRORS

```
[Error] invalid operands of types 'int' and 'float' to binary 'operator%'
[Error] invalid operands of types 'float' and 'float' to binary 'operator%'
```

Comment: What isn't clear? You can't use the modulus operator on floating point numbers. It's only applicable to integers.

Comment: Error messages are supposed to be read. They are also good to google.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot obtain mod of float and int objects together. if you need integer mod then

```
float a = 10.0;
int b = 10;
// parse float to int and get the mod
int mod = b % ((int)a);
```

if you want absolute mod

```
float a = 10.5;
int b = 100;
int d = b / a;
float mod = b - (a * d);
```

Edit as per suggestion:
use `fmod` function. defined in `<math.h>`
[fmod reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/)

Comment: yup. I was just explaining how it should be. I'll add that as well. thanks for telling that